# Selection event in perl tk

Tags: perl, selection, tk-toolkit

I have the following `Scrolled` widget in my perl GUI script which uses Tk

```
my $text_area = $main_window->Scrolled("Text", -scrollbars => 'se' , background => 'white')->pack(-expand => 1, -fill => 'both');
```

My question is how to `add a selection event` ie, when I click and select some part of the text (range) inside the widget .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the virtual event `<<Selection>>`:

```
$text_area->bind('<<Selection>>' => sub { ... });
```

Comment: am I doing it wrong then ? the following is my code but it doesnt do anything
    `$text_area->bind('<<Selection>>' => sub {$text_area->insert('end', "\n selected"); });`

Comment: Works on my system (freebsd 9, Perl/Tk 804.031) (though I'm getting _too_ many events). What's your system?

Comment: RHEL 6 , Tk (version 804.031)

Comment: Sometimes, when dealing with Scrolled widgets, one has to explicitly specify the embedded widget: `$text_area->Subwidget("scrolled")->bind(...)`. But this does not seem to be the case on my system. Another idea, maybe it's window manager-dependent? Which one are you using?

Comment: I tried your last suggestion it didn't work , but before going further , I would like to know whether my question is correct , because what i wanted to achieve is I want the sub call to take place when the user selects some part of the text inside that text area by clicking and  dragging acress the text by either mouse or keyboard .

Comment: Basically it should work. The `<<Selection>>` event is called on every (possible) change of the selection. That is very often; a simple mouse click for example is resetting a selection, so `<<Selection>>` is also called. Also while a user is dragging the mouse, a lot of `<<Selection>>` events are called. To make the functionality usable, you probably need to delay the callback, e.g. by using `->after()` (and don't forget to cancel older `->after()` callbacks).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36717/discussion-between-user94962-and-slaven-rezic)